# Mixin extends another Mixin in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mixins, lit

I have the following mixin:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export declare class MixknAInterface {
    // methods goes here
}

export const MixinA = <T extends Constructor<LitElement>>(superclass: T) => {
    class MixinAClass extends superclass {
        ...
    }
    return MixinAClass as unknown as Constructor<MixknAInterface> & T;
}
```

And this is how one component extends it:

```
export class ClassA extends MixinA(LitElement) {...}
```

But what if I want to create another mixin `MixinB` that extends `MixinA` so that I can have a component extending on `MixinB` and `MixinA` like

```
export class ClassB extends MixinB.....
```

How should I create `MixinB`?

Comment: Regarding ... _"How should I create `MixinB`?"_ ... exactly how you did with what you call `MixinA`, so that in the end you have to use it like ... `const ClassB = MixinB(MixinA(LitElement))` or `ClassC extends MixinB(MixinA(LitElement))`. But what this class based, so called _"mixin"_ pattern, actually achieves, is dynamic subclassing. It is not a classic mixin based composition-pattern, it is pure inheritance, using the dynamic nature of JavaScript, here features implemented within an ad-hoc created class which extends any passed other class.

Comment: Thus, with the given example code, following question does arise ... Why using the above pattern at all? Why not implementing all code straightforwardly like ... `class ComponentA extends LitElement { /* custom implementation */ }` ... followed by ... `class ComponentB extends ComponentA { /* custom implementation */ }` ... followed by ... `class TargetComponent extends ComponentB { /* custom implementation */ }` ... which does exactly what the OP tries to achieve with the above fake-mixin pattern that, by type definition, actually is allowed to dynamically subclass just `LitElement`.

Comment: One benefit of a mixin is that you can inject it between the hierarchy. If you already have `BaseElement extends LitElement` and `FooElement extends BaseElement`, you can apply the mixin like `CustomFoo extends mixin(FooElement)`, without changing the `BaseElement`. If the mixin was instead a subclass of `LitElement`, you'd need to replace it on `BaseElement` as well.

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev ... Regarding all the comments, are there any questions left?